# Jquery Mobile refresh list

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, refresh

I'm using jQuery Mobile for the first time (in fact, anything jQuery related) and I've managed to place some nested listviews to show content.
How can I do to refresh those nested lists? I've seen there's a refresh() function, but I don't know exactly where/how to use it or it it suits my needs.
Can someone help my with this?

Comment: where have you seen the `jquery refresh` function

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant this:  $('ul').listview('refresh'); from the jQuery Mobile docs

Comment: can you post some sample code and the intended output you want i dont understand what you mean by *refresh*

Answer (score 1):

This post shows examples of how to call refresh

[Don’t forget to call refresh when adding items to your jQuery Mobile list](http://operationmobile.com/dont-forget-to-call-refresh-when-adding-items-to-your-jquery-mobile-list/)